# Typscript if guard not narrowing value for inline closure

Tags: typescript

May someone help me understand, why compiler is complaining about the type mismatch in below code:

```
function printSomeValue(someValue: string) {
    console.log(`${someValue}`)
}

function doSomething(closure: () => void) {
    closure()
}

let str: string | undefined

str = 'It should work'

if (str) {
    doSomething(() => printSomeValue(str))
}
```

So, issue is on this line `doSomething(() => printSomeValue(str))` as it is complaining the type of `str` is `string | undefined` and not `string`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAynAtgUwDUBDAGxHwAoBnPIsigLkWqnTAHMBKRAbwChEQxBAS1S+AHSk4HSgAMAJL1oES5fAF95Xfpv79QkWAkQATODgJQAFhjkQZ1EKnzNKPALwA+RADc4GDMeAWERJxcqXX1+CSgWNmZWdg5EAB9EcDN8YAx8MwNkxE9EAHIASXjqGzgQUjNEAHc4VABrUoMYYEQaNhDBYQsrfFt7Sg9i3zQMbDp1Cl7ULmigA)

Comment: You can see if you call `printSomeValue` directly that `str` _has_ been narrowed correctly: https://tsplay.dev/wgQ40m. But when you're deferring that call by passing a callback the compiler won't guarantee it's still defined by the time the call happens.

Comment: Because it's true. `str` is explicitly defined as type `string | undefined`. Even if the value is a string, it still reads `typeof str` as `string | undefined`.

Comment: @Archigan inside the block guarded by `if (str)`, `str` is narrowed to `string`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe got it.

Comment: Might I also make a suggestion to use semicolons? Yes the compiler does add them, but it makes it much more readable in my opinion. This isn't python or any other language that doesn't use them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe why compiler cannot guarantee in case of callback here?

Comment: @code_mechanic because it could get reassigned before it gets used. There's only so much control flow analysis the compiler will do.

Comment: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAynAtgUwDUBDAGxHwAoBnPIsigLkWqnTAHMBKRAbwChEQxBAS1S+AHSk4HSgAMAJL1oES5fAF95Xfpv79QkWAkQATODgJQAFhjkQZ1EKnzNKPALwA+RADc4GDMeAWEWfCgAFRgCOBAoSg9EHxEnFyouABpEAFYABjyuAG49AwkoFjZmVnYORAAfRHAzfGAMfDMDGuTEAHIASQrqGzjSM0QAdzhUAGtegxhgRBo2EMFhCysIu05Er180DGw6dQoV1ABCLl19bs8msBa2sA6SoA) is a practical example of what could go wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't assume type guards remain active in callbacks, as making this assumption is dangerous (pay attention to [this](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#type-guards-and-callbacks)).

What you can do is something like this:

```
if (str) {
  const newStr = str;
  doSomething(() => printSomeValue(newStr));
}
```

Store the **type narrowed** variable (`str`), in a constant to tell the compiler, this constant (`newStr`) will not be changed. Then TypeScript will understand that.

I explain, why it is dangerous with an example:

```
let val = "A text for testing";

const myFunction = (value) => {
    console.log(value.length);
}

setTimeout(() => {
    val = undefined;
},3000)

if(val !== undefined){
    document.getElementById("clickable")
     .addEventListener("click",() => {myFunction(val)});
}
```

Consider that you have a button with `clickable` id and If `val` is **not undefined**, you want to add a click event listener to it.
If you click the button before the `setTimeOut` callback is triggered,  `myFunction` runs currectly but after the `setTimeout` function is called, it throws an error (*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')*). Because `val`, has been changed from a higher scope and it affects the event Listener callback behaviour.
So the condition:

`if(val !== undefined)`

can not guarantee that `val` will never have `undefined` value.

But if you store the value of `val` in a constant like `newVal` and use `newVal` in the event listener, the problem will be solved:

```
if(val !== undefined){
    const newVal = val;
    document.getElementById("clickable")
     .addEventListener("click",() => {myFunction(newVal)});
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I get the possible solution to the issue but the example in the link you posted doesn't explain why it is dangerous with some example, if you can add that example in your answer I can accept it.